NSMuatableAttributedString's appendString method only exist in iPhone-device build in iOS18, and not exist in Simulator-build
I have defined a method appendString method in a NSMuatableAttributedString category like this:
@implementation NSMutableAttributedString (HTML)


// appends a plain string extending the attributes at this position
- (void)appendString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSParameterAssert(string);
    
    NSUInteger length = [self length];
...

And this method is worked well in iOS17 and before .
But when it cames iOS18 . this appendString will not be called.
So I doubt maybe there is a system-defined appendString already.
So I write a demo in empty project to print all the NSMuatableAttributedString method in iOS18 like these:
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

void printNSStringCategories() {
    unsigned int count;
    Class nsStringClass = [NSMutableAttributedString class];

    
    // 获取所有的方法
    Method *methods = class_copyMethodList(nsStringClass, &count);
    
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        SEL selector = method_getName(methods[i]);
        NSString *methodName = NSStringFromSelector(selector);
        NSLog(@"NSMutableAttributedString method: %@", methodName);
    }
    
    free(methods);
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    printNSStringCategories();
}

And test it in my iPhone (iOS18.2) , the log will printed
NSMutableAttributedString method: appendString:withAttributes:
NSMutableAttributedString method: cr_appendStorage:fromRange:
NSMutableAttributedString method: cr_appendString:
NSMutableAttributedString method: appendString:withAttributes:
NSMutableAttributedString method: appendString:

So it seems a appendString: is aleady defined in system SDK .
But the weird thing is when I run this code in the Xcode simulator (iOS18.1)
this appendString: will not print .
1 Is it a bug of SDK ? because the appendString: only exist in device-build , and not exist in simulator-build?
two more furthur question:
2.1 if the SDK contains appendString: already , why the appendString: defined in my category not cause the duplicate symbol error when compile
2.2 As the question 2.1 said , there maybe same symbols in runtime . Is there any way to find the framework/library which defined those same-name symbols ? (e.g: there are two appendString:withAttributes: in the log , I want to find the two places define each appendString:withAttributes: exactly)

Tip: run and pause the app and execute debugger command image lookup -rn NSMutableAttributedString or image lookup -rn appendString:.

@Willeke ,thanks ! works like charm!  seems ScreenReaderCore`-[NSMutableAttributedString(SCRCMutableAttributedStringExtras) appendString:] has defined in the system !  My 2.2 question is solved !!

Thanks @Willeke for your tips ,now I know the whole thing behind this problem.
As the image lookup -rn NSMutableAttributedString says
There will be a appendString defined in ScreenReaderCore framework
ScreenReaderCore`-[NSMutableAttributedString(SCRCMutableAttributedStringExtras) appendString:] 

For Question 1:
there  will be duplicate methods for sure !
And because this ScreenReaderCore is seemd to used for Voice-Over .  The simulator is not using this framework . So this duplication  exist only in real device.
For question 2.1
The method duplication in different category can not be found by the compilor , and this function will be invoked is undefined , It's very dangerous , So it's better to add prefix to the method name in catetory.
For question 2.2:
Just as @Willeke comment.
run and pause the app and execute debugger command
image lookup -rn NSMutableAttributedString or image lookup -rn appendString:. – 

